# jQuery set alternating color rows

Tags: jquery, css, rows, alternating

I'm looking for a specific answer to my question. And this is, I have a row containing a quantity of divs (is dynamically set).
What I want is alternately the background of divs (3 divs) are set to another color like this:
[image]
Can this be done by the CSS odd and even pseudo classes or should this be done through jQuery?

Comment: You can probably do this in CSS using the `nth` selector. Can you post your HTML in the question too, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by adding this to your CSS.. `foo:nth-child(n+3)`

**UPDATED:**

```
ul li:nth-child(6n+4),
ul li:nth-child(6n+5),
ul li:nth-child(6n+6) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

^ Altough I'm not a fan, it works.

http://codepen.io/pacMakaveli/pen/JdWYoM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're absolutely right.. I misread the question, please see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using:

```css
li:nth-child(6n),
li:nth-child(6n - 1),
li:nth-child(6n - 2) {background: red;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oops took me so long to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding td:nth-child(3n) it may works for you